# Can u recommend a telephone emulator software?

Tags: windows, phone

I am trying to use my laptop's modem card to make phone calls because I have to make a lot of  phone calls everyday.

I know windows 7 has a program called dialer that could do it.  But need something more powerful, that could remember more phone numbers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm 99% sure it's not compatible with a phone card, but you could use [Skype](http://www.skype.com/intl/en-us/home) and ditch the phone line.

Comment: +1 ditch the card. Skype is basically VoIP for your computer, it's cheaper than standard phone service, you can do conference calls between multiple people for no extra charge, and video chat if you have a webcam.